# Getting Xbox Live via a wired network with my laptop that has internet access wirelessly

Tags: network-bridge

I'm running the latest version (as of yesterday anyways) of Ubuntu Desktop 64bit, but installed on my laptop if it makes a difference. I had Windows 7 preinstalled when i bought it and it worked fine with the wireless from my house and bridging the connection with a LAN to my xbox for Live. Now with Ubuntu I tried the same setup, but I'm unfamiliar with Ubuntu so I didn't get far. Best I got so far is wireless internet on my laptop and a wired connection to the xbox that continually connects and disconnects.

Heres my network settings. if theres fields not included its because theyre empty on mine
or theyre my MAC address or network password

**Wireless Network 1 settings:**

Connect Automatically: Checked.

Available to all Users: Checked

**Wireless:**

SSID: Franco's

Mode: Infrastructure

MTU: Automatic

**IPv4 Settings:**

Method: Automatic (DHCP)

**IPv6 Settings:**

Method: Automatic

**Wired Network 1:**

Connect Automatically: Checked

Available to all Users: Checked

**Wired:**

MTU: Automatic

**IPv4 Settings:**

Method: Automatic (DHCP)

**IPv6 Settings:**

Method: Automatic

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: 6:26pm
It seems to be staying connected now. Doing the Network test on my xbox it pickups the network, but cannot detect any PC. Restarting the Xbox, however, leaves my computer unable to connect bringing up the Wire Network disconnected 'blip' every minute or so again. Before I had restarted the Xbox it said "Connected 100 MB/s". Now it only says "connecting". I did have my computer and xbox on in this Wired Network Disconnected blip cycle for a long period of time so it may have finally connected, just without the ability to detect my laptop. I left for 2 hours or so in the middle of typing up the original question. I finished posting this when i got back and then tried to mess with it a bit again, in case youre wondering why i didnt include this before... I've said too much. Forgive my long-winded fingers :p

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Network Manager can't do network bridging.  To do that, I think your best bet is editing `/etc/network/interfaces`.  I'm afraid that's where my knowledge ends; never had to bridge wireless to wired, just wired to KVM virtual network.

Oh, and you'll need the `bridge-utils` package.

Comment: What are these "packages" I keep hearing about? Forgive my ignorance, I'm still new to Ubuntu. I've always had Windows my whole life, but I'm getting a little bored of it. My A+ teacher recommended Ubuntu.

Comment: A package is a bundle of files that get installed, roughly analogous to a Windows MSI package or a Mac .pkg file.  It could be software, or documentation, or data files.  A package might require other packages, and those should be automatically installed along with it. You can install it from the command line with `sudo apt-get bridge-utils` and your password, or through the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for your help, I'll tinker around with this and see if I can get it.

Comment: I'm new to the whole console commands as well... I'm not yet even a Padawan in Ubuntu. I've much to learn. Assistance, if possible, would be greatly appreciated. Much thanks

Comment: I'd be happy to answer any other questions you can pose on Ask Ubuntu.  Make sure they follow the usual guidelines, and can help others.  If you use this to eventually answer your question about bridging, make sure to come back and write it down :)

Comment: No solution yet found.

Comment: Solved. All I did was go to Wired Connect 1, IPv4 Settings, Method: Share to Other Computers. Kept the wireless connection Automatic (DHCP). Annoyingly simple.